# ¿Por qué me dice workbench que hay un error al crear la tabla?

Tags: sql-server, mysql-workbench

este es el script

```
Create table Clientes(
Rfc_Clientes varchar(45),
Nombre varchar(45),
Paterno varchar (45),
Materno varchar(45),
Calle varchar(45),
Colonia varchar(45),
Numext varchar(45),
Numint int,
Id_Orden varchar(45) unique null,
Primary key rfc(id_Cliente),
Foreign key(id_Orden) references Ordenes(id_Orden)
);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor haz el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Debes tratar de especificar tu problema indicando los mensajes de error que recibes. Adicionalmente, sólo son pertinentes las etiquetas relacionadas con el **script** que muestras.

Comment: tienes que revisar los nombres, porque tienen que ser EXACTAMENTE IGUALES, en tu script estas usando `id_Orden` en vez de `Id_Orden` y no existe `id_Cliente`

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Deberías poner en tu pregunta (siempre, no sólo esta vez) el mensaje de error específico que te está entregando el Workbench. Ahí segurisísimo se queja por `Primary key rfc(id_Cliente),` porque, cuál será la columna id_Cliente a la que hace referencia?? Una llave primaria debe referenciar un campo **de la misma tabla**

Answer (score 0):

Parece que la llave primaria hace referencia a un campo que no está declarado en la creación de la tabla:
"Primary key rfc(id_Cliente)"
En todo caso, debería hacer referencia a: Rfc_Clientes